# Sharepoint: Trying to get the highest ows_ID inclusive of deleted items

Tags: sharepoint

I am using SharePoint web service and am trying to return the highest ID number from a list. My scenario is like say I have 10 items in a list. Highest ows_ID at this point is 10. Now, if I delete an item and check the max of ows_ID, I got 9, however the highest ows_ID is 10 inclusive of deletion.

If a new item gets inserted, it gets the ows_ID as 11 instead of 10.  In the same way, is it possible to get the highest ows_ID even though the item is deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You can call GetList to see the highest ID used. That method returns information about the list itself rather than the items in it.

Comment: I dont see the ID is returned in GetList method. Can you please let me know what is the element name in GetList that return the ID value?

Answer (score 0):

Try "rowLimit", configure your CAML to do your stuff and only get the first item in the search criteria:

```
                string rowLimit = "1";
                System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
                System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
                System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
                query.InnerXml = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"FileLeafRef\"/><Value Type=\"" + fieldType + "\">" + fieldValue + "</Value></Eq></Where> ";
                viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\""+fieldToGet+"\" />";
                queryOptions.InnerXml = "";
                System.Xml.XmlNode nodes = myservice.GetListItems(listGuid, viewGuid, query, viewFields, rowLimit, null, null);
```

In my example below,  I just get the last created item, using some criteria, but as You don't need this, just fix the caml in my code.